# Why when use @Autowired in @Configuration in Spring failed sometimes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with a thrift server, and I have two @Configuration class with two bean generation method, and the code is as following:

```
@Configuration
public class EagleBeanCreator {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public EagleRestClient build() {
        EagleRestClient client = new EagleRestClient();
        // some set values code
        return client;
    }
}
```

And another one:

```
@Configuration
public class EagleServiceBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private EagleRestClient eagleProxy;

    @Bean
    public EagleService eagleService() {
        EagleService service = new EagleService();
        System.out.println(eagleProxy);
        service.setEagleProxy(eagleProxy);
        return service;
    }
}
```

But when I run spring-boot:run, it print out null for "System.out.println(eagleProxy);"
Why?

=========================UPDATE=============================

I know setter injection or constructor injection works.

Comment: You might find it works in some builds and then not in others due to the eager instantiation of `@Bean` methods in `@Configuration` classes. Use the answer provided by @DKD to ensure your @Bean method receives its constructed dependencies as constructor args or rely on hacks like `@Lazy` to prevent eager instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the order to load `EagleBeanCreator` and `EagleServiceBuilder` is not definite. You can use `@Order` or `@ConditionalOnClass` to make sure `EagleBeanCreator` initialize first.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try this out.

```
@Configuration
public class EagleServiceBuilder {

    @Bean
    public EagleService eagleService(EagleRestClient eagleProxy) {
        EagleService service = new EagleService();
        System.out.println(eagleProxy);
        service.setEagleProxy(eagleProxy);
        return service;
    }
}
```

My guess is that the way you currently implement doesn't indicate a dependency between the `EagleService` and `EagleRestClient`. So your current implementation leads to random initialization order between the two beans. The modified version tells Spring "Hey, my EagleService depends on `EagleRestClient`. Please initialize `EagleRestClient` before `EagleService`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually know this works, but I want to know why my code doesn't work :(

Comment: @Gao This is something related to how Spring determines dependencies among the beans. Your current implementation doesn't imply that dependency exists.

Comment: A good solution for interfaces that have problems when autowired (not initialized on time)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `@Configuration` bean are initialized in the same phase of bean lifecycle. I don't remember them clearly but something like:

`Configurations -> Components -> Services`

With the beans in the same phase, if they depend on each other, you should declare the load order by some `@Conditional` or `@Order`

Answer (score 0):

Add @DependsOn("eagleRestClient") annotation on the definition of EagleService.

```
@DependsOn("eagleRestClient")
@Bean
 public EagleService eagleService() {
       EagleService service = new 
       EagleService();
       System.out.println(eagleProxy);
       service.setEagleProxy(eagleProxy);
        return service;
  }
```

Spring will then first create rest client then the eagle service.

Answer (score -3):

First, you need to get the spring container through  `ApplicationContextAware` try

```
ApplicationContext.getBean(EagleRestClient.class)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `ApplicationContext` or `BeanFactory` in your code directly, that generally is an indication that you are doing things in a wrong way.

Comment: Why? Is there a bug?

Comment: You should be using dependency injection plus the fact that you don't want to tie your application code to Spring with using the `ApplicationContext` to do bean lookup.